# remove the vowels and insert '*'

Tags: python, list, iteration

my objective is: **Write a function called remove_vowels that takes a string as input and returns a new version of that string with the vowels replaced by '*'.**

```
def remove_vowels(data):
  empty = ""
  for char in data:
    if char in 'aeiou':
      empty += '*'
    else:
      return empty += letter
```

whenever I run this i get the error: **Unexpected token var**

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assignments (even in-place assignments like +=) are statements, not expressions, and you can only return expressions. You probably want to return the new string *after* the loop.

Comment: Side thought: You may wish to exclude upper and lowercase letters, e.g. `'aeiouAEIOU'`

Answer (score 4):

The result of an assignment `empty += letter` isn't a value, so you can't pass it to return and you don't want to.  You also used letter in your code instead of char which you used as the variable name earlier. The correct code is:

```
def remove_vowels(data):
  empty = ""
  for char in data:
    if char in 'aeiou':
      empty += '*'
    else:
      empty += char
  return empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are `return`-ing the value of an in-place modifier, which is `None`. Also, the `return` should be later in your code, because a `return` acts as a `break`.

You should use something like the following:

```
def remove_letters(data):
    data = ''.join(['*' if char in 'aeiou' else char for char in data])
    return data
```

---

```
>>> remove_letters('string')
'str*ng'
>>> remove_letters('octopus')
'*ct*p*s'
>>>
```

Comment: It's not true that the value of an augmented assignment is `None`. It's a statement; it _has_ no value. If you want to stretch things, it's implemented with __iadd__ or __add__, which return the updated value. There's nothing evaluating to `None` here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other way just for fun:

```
data = "Whatever string you can put here"
x = data.replace("a", "*").replace("e", "*").replace("i", "*").replace("o", "*").replace("u", "*")
print x
```

The output is this:

`Wh*t*v*r str*ng y** c*n p*t h*r*`